# How to access enclosing function's arguments from within a macro?

Tags: cmake

I want to implement a macro that works like `cmake_parse_arguments(PARSE_ARGV ...)`, i.e. one that accesses the arguments of the enclosing function. Unfortunately, `${ARGN}`, `${ARGC}` and `${ARGVn}` have a special meaning within a macro and they invoke macro parameter string substitutions. I would want to access the `ARGN` and `ARGC` and `ARGVn` variables of the *enclosing function's scope*.

Answer (score 0):

The way around it is to use an intervening variable reference as an escape. Only the innermost substitution is a macro substition, thus `${${}ARGV0}` is macro-substituted to `${${}ARGV0}`, then first variable substitution gives `${ARGV0}` and the second variable substitution yields the value of first argument in the innermost function scope enclosing the macro.

Thus:

```
macro (show_arg1)
  message("1:${${}ARGV1}")
endmacro()

function (test_function)
  show_arg1()
endfunction()

test_function(foo bar baz)
```

Output:

```
1:bar
```

This allows to implement macros that behave like `cmake_parse_arguments` but do something else while still parsing the arguments of the enclosing functions.

Should the `${}` variable substitution ever trigger an error, one could use any unset variable, eg. `${${mgUXpKW8srYnwnSP}ARGV1}`.